# Removing border

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I am trying to remove a grey border from a iframe box, but having difficulty

the code is the following, with source removed. I have also attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5i5T.png) showing the border

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe
      frameborder="0"
      height="100%"
      src=""
      width="100%"
    >
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us the source?

Answer (score 0):

Body tag puts 8px margin by default.Try this.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
     body{ margin:0px;padding:0px; }
    </style>
    <iframe
      frameborder="0"
      height="100%"
      src=""
      width="100%"
    >
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no still has the annoying grey border, thanks though

Comment: can you give a link to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Use  ( I think spelling mistake on above )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe
      frameBorder="0"
      height="100%"
      src=""
      width="100%"
    >
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```